# Activeadmin, polymorphic relationship and nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have 2 models: `Provider` and `Delivery`. The `Note` model belongs to either of the two, by polymorphism (`belongs_to`).
The `Provider` model looks like this:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :site_url, :brand_ids, :note_attributes
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_one :note
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :note, allow_destroy: true
end
```

The form to create a new provider renders with no problem, but when I try to save it I get the following error:

```
unknown attribute: provider_id
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Note model should have `attr_accessible :provider_id`

Comment: Delivery? Are you sure? I trying to create provider model and nested note.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Note` model.

Comment: Nothing happens. Note hasn't provider_id in db table, only notable_id.

Comment: Please post the contents of all your models. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to add `as: :notable` to `has_one :note`. Now, everything fine. Thank you for your time!